# what's the difference between "the" and blank?

Tags: articles

I have a sentence but I don't know how to fill it. When I don't use *the,* it seems pretty sensible. When I use it, it seems sensible too. I'm writing the sentence below.

> An infographic is ....... kind of illustration which .... public
>   enjoys looking at to understand statistical facts.

Comment: The choice is between “the” and “a” for the first blank. The second blank can only take “the”.    Is the infographic the only kind of illustration or one of many that the public enjoys looking at to understand statistical facts?

Comment: ELU has a question about [indefinite/definite/zero articles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) which would answer this question, but it seems likely an ELL answer would be better.

Comment: Can we leave the second blank empty?

Answer (score 1):

A general rule I follow is for non-plural nouns, insert an article. In your case, "the" should be used for both spaces so that the sentence reads,

"An infographic is **the** kind of illustration which **the** public enjoys looking at to understand statistical facts."

NOTE: The article "a" can be used for the first blank--"... is a kind of illustration..."-- but NOT for the second blank, because only one public is referred to in this context.

Comment: To me, the choice of “a” or “the” comes down to their use of “that” or “which” .  It’s “***the*** kind of illustration ***that***” or “***a*** kind of illustration ***which***”  Since they’ve used *which* the choice is “***a***”.

Comment: I do not think that is a good general rule. It doesn't work in all cases, or even in a vast majority of cases. There are plenty of non-plural nouns that rarely take articles, and plenty that often take articles but may not depending on context. Abstract nouns like "friendship" or "freedom" rarely take an article, although they can. Uncountable nouns in general tend to eschew articles, and you would say "milk is healthy", not "the milk is healthy", although of course you do add a definite article when you are specifically *definining*: "the milk *that I bought today* was off".